# H2 Zoom mic on Ubuntu Studio 20.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, 20.10

I have an H2 Zoom mic, which I used as a USB mic until 20.10. It no longer works.

When I open it with `alsamixer`, it tells me "This sound device does not have any controls."

The contents of `/proc/asound/H2` are

```
id  pcm0c  pcm0p  stream0  usbbus  usbid  usbmixer
```

The contents of `stream0` are:

```
ZOOM Corporation H2 at usb-0000:39:00.0-2.3, full speed : USB Audio

Playback:
  Status: Stop
  Interface 1
    Altset 1
    Format: S16_LE
    Channels: 2
    Endpoint: 5 OUT (ADAPTIVE)
    Rates: 44100, 48000
    Bits: 16
    Channel map: FL FR

Capture:
  Status: Stop
  Interface 2
    Altset 1
    Format: S16_LE
    Channels: 2
    Endpoint: 5 IN (ASYNC)
    Rates: 44100, 48000
    Bits: 16
    Channel map: FL FR
```

Has ALSA dropped support for this microphone? Is there a way I can get and enable legacy support? Or is something else wrong?

Update:
I plugged this into a different computer also running Ubuntu studio. Alsa also says it has no controls, but it shows up in the settings app and I'm able to use it. It's running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and the one that doesn't work is running 20.10.  What's missing on 20.10 and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a work-around that has got the mic working.

As normal, I plug in the mic and set it as an interface and it doesn't work.

Then, on the mic, I hit the menu button and scroll down until I reach the input option. I turned the input off. Then turn it back on.

Then, back on the computer, in settings, I set the mic input to H2.  Now it works.

Literally, turning it off and back on again, but in the software on the mic.  For more details on this, see the manual: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/458720/Zoom-Handy-Recorder-H2.html?page=76#manual